# My-Weather-Indicator Widget Blank

Tags: upgrade, my-weather-indicator

My weather indicator was working fine when i was on Ubuntu LTS 14.04. I then upgraded to 14.10 and it stopped working as in the widget appears blank and just creates a black box. Not sure what is the issue. I tried Clearing the Configs ,Installing multiple time but no luck..:(

How to debug what is the issue ?.. where can i see the reason for failure?.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your software sources. You may still be using the Trusty (14.04) PPA. It appears that there are packages available for Utopic see: https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao?field.series_filter=utopic

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-weather-indicator-widget-ubuntu-1410/

i was following this link and this seems to be pointed to right PPA. Please correct me if i am wrong?..

Comment: I Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your software sources. You may still be using the Trusty (14.04) PPA. It appears that there are packages available for Utopic see: https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao?field.series_filter=utopic It's possible the extras available for Utopic will resolve your issue. If not, you may be effected by this (or another) bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1438472